# Place tabItem of TabBar in middle and upon clicking next tab, it will starts shifting to left?

Tags: java, android, tabs

Tab item should start from middle of the mobile device,when we are clicking any tabitem. Tabitem should be in middle.When it reaches end , tabitem should be in middle. like first positon from end .
[image: Tablayout view should be in this from]

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#F43737"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="1dp"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#111" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#DCD8D8" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Java Code

```
    tabLayout=findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager=findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);

    for (int k = 0; k <10; k++) {
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("" + k));
    }

    PlansPagerAdapter adapter = new PlansPagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager));
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));//Bonus Code : If your tab layout has more than 2 tabs then tab will scroll other wise they will           take whole width of the screen
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
```

Comment: show your XML layout

Comment: Added xml and Java code what iam using  @Niceumang

Comment: tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE); try after remove this line.

Comment: @Niceumang i need my tabitem to look like that image

Comment: @MujeebRahamanT you can get above result using custome library , are you flexible with it?

Comment: @Niceumang No .. i need that kind of tabitem which i shared in image.